# Opcode reading of a classfile at runtime with the use of ASM4

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, opcodes

Does anybody have any document, which can show me end to end implementation of ASM framework  to display opcode of a class file? Or is there any body help me with Hello, World! Program example for ASM frame implementation?
I want to display opcodes of any class file with the help of ASM frame work, just like we get with JAVAP command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Oracle has a webpage dedicated for this.
The webpage can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html)

Comment: I wanted to know the implementation of ASM frame work to get the opcodes of class file. Do you know any implementation document which shows us end to end coding?